In surreal numbers, what is the successor of all the germs in the Hardy field?
I have my own totally ordered hierarchy of quantities, including infinite ones. Can I embeed them in surreal numbers somehow?
For instance, I have the quantity $\omega$, which I identify with the similarly-denoted surreal number.
I also have a quantity $\alpha$, which is greater than any transseries or their generalization of $\omega$. Would such quantity be embedded into surreal numbers? How could I represent it in $\{L|R\}$ form?
To be more specific, is there a surreal number that is the first-born number greater than the set of germs in maximal Hardy field, in other words, $\{H|\}$?

I agree with the thrust of Joel's remarks. There is, however, an important recent result that I believe is worth adding to the discussion.
In their (Surreal numbers, derivations and transseries, J. Eur. Math. Soc. 20 (2018), pp. 339–390), Berarducci and Montova construct a derivation $\partial$ on $\bf{No}$ (the surreals) having some nice proprties. Using the restriction $\partial_{\omega_1}$ of $\partial$ to $\bf{No}(\omega_1)$, where  $\bf{No}(\omega_1)$ is the set of all surreal numbers having tree-rank (or birthday)  $< \omega_1$, Aschenbrenner, van den Dries and van der Hoeven (Filling gaps in Hardy Fields, arXiv:2308.02446v1, 4 Aug 2023) have shown:
Proposition:
Assuming CH, every maximal Hardy field is isomorphic to $(\bf{No}(\omega_1), \partial_{\omega_1})$.
While there is no least surreal number greater than every member of $\bf{No}(\omega_1)$, there is a unique surreal number of least tree-rank
(or birthday) greater than every member of $\bf{No}(\omega_1)$, namely $\omega_1$. Accordingly, since (assuming CH) every maximal Hardy field is a universal Hardy field, $\omega_1$ is also the unique surreal number of least tree-rank (or birthday) greater than this distinguished isomorphic copy of a universal Hardy field.

Thanks, so the answer seems to be positive. I am only confused, why in surreal numbers $\ln \omega=\omega^{1/\omega}$ but in Hardy fields $\ln x\ne x^{1/x}$, if they are isomorphic? But perhaps, it is suitable for a separate question...

Do I understand correctly, $\omega_1$ is a specific surreal number (I could not find this notation in Wikipedia)? Does it mean the first uncountable ordinal?

$\omega_1$ is the least uncountable ordinal

@Anixx $(\bf{No}(\omega_1), \partial_{\omega_1})$ is not a Hardy field, it is an isomorphic copy of a Hardy field.

Thanks, this is interesting. And in line with my expectation. Actually, my question was realated to the numerocities. The numerocities of countable sets can be embedded into Hardy field (each numerocity is the equivalence class of infinitesimally close germs). And I speculated that the numerocity of an interval can be that $\alpha$ https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/59575/is-there-an-alternative-to-cantors-cardinalities-that-makes-proper-subsets-smal/112762#112762.

But if we take the germ $x$ as $\omega$ then $\alpha$ is the numerocity of $[0,\pi)$. If we take the germ of $x/\pi$ as $\omega$, then $\alpha$ would be the numerocity of $[0,1)$. I wonder, whether this theory tells that $\omega_1$ should denote exactly the numerocity of $[0,\pi)$ and not $[0,1)$?

"it is an isomorphic copy of a Hardy field" - then the equivalence $\ln \omega=\omega^{1/\omega}$ should hold in the both, no?

Philip, do you take the result as evidence in favor of the continuum hypothesis? That would be an argument similar to the theme of my recent article, on which I spoke at Irvine: https://jdh.hamkins.org/how-ch-could-have-been-fundamental-irvine-march-2024/.

Under CH, it seems to me that $\text{No}(\omega_1)$ is a saturated ordered field of size $\omega_1$. Thus, it is universal for all ordered fields of that size. But also it is resplendent, and so can accept a differential operator while remaining saturated. Is this basically the proof of the proposition?

@JoelDavidHamkins something looks fishy to me with this actually. I am going to write a question on this. Who decided that all countable surreals should be contained in this Hardy field? Why $\omega_1$ is uncountable? The problem is, there are two different multiplication operations. One is compatible with germ multiplication, the other one is more like Cartesian muntiplication. And $\omega\cdot\omega$ using Cartesian multiplication seems to be greater than any germ, but still countable.

@JoelDavidHamkins For instance, $\omega^2$ using germ multiplication is $\int_0^\infty (2x)dx$ but using Cartesian multiplication it is $\int_0^{\infty } \left(\frac{1}{4} \pi ^2 \cot ^2\left(\frac{\pi  x}{2}\right)+\frac{\pi ^2}{4}\right) , dx$. But according to Euclid's principle the later should be greater than any Hardy germ. And the both are countable.

@Anixx Many of your comments seem to presume that operations and concepts well-defined on the real numbers are also automatically meaningful on the surreal numbers. But this is just not true. We've already observed that as an ordered field, all infinite surreal numbers look alike and are isomorphic by an automorphism of the surreals. So one should be much more precise about the exact structure when you are applying trig functions and integration, etc. These necessarily don't have definite meaning. And any field that embeds into the surreals with infinite numbers necessarily has many copies.

In particular, under CH every ordered field of size continuum has a copy inside $\text{NO}(\omega_1)$, which is what the saturation result I mentioned gives. Although those fields also have many other copies higher up in the surreals, they also have a copy within $\text{No}(\omega_1)$. And by resplendency, if one can put a differential operator on any elementary extension of it, then one can already have it on that field. So the universality applies with that structure.

@JoelDavidHamkins they are defined. It is just too cumbersome for a comment. I will try to explain my concerns in a question.

They are provably not unique by the saturation analysis.

@JoelDavidHamkins my point is, the numerosity of any set that has accumulation points (or dense) is greater than numerosity of any monotonous sequence (that can be seen as corresponding to a Hardy germ). Similarly, any (everywhere positive) divergent integral with poles is greater than any divergent integral of a monotonously growhing continuous function(which also corresponds to a Hardy germ). And this follows from Euclid's principle (seemingly).

No set of surreal numbers has accumulation points, and no set of surreals is dense on any interval. Nor does any sequence converge, even transfinite length sequences. No filters converge. Integrals cannot be defined as the "limit" of finite sums, since limits don't exist. But still, you seem to use all these concepts in the surreals anyway without remark. Because of saturation, it will be a meta theorem that if you can find a concept of numerosity in the surreals, then it will not be unique.

@JoelDavidHamkins I was talking about sequences of reals and accumulation points on the real line...

@JoelDavidHamkins here I wrote the question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/473202/why-is-it-said-that-all-surreal-numbers-with-birthdate-omega-1-are-isomorphi

The central construction feature of the surreal numbers is that it is Ord-saturated, which means that for any sets of surreal numbers $A$ and $B$, with $A<B$ in the sense that every element of $A$ is less than every element of $B$, then there is a surreal number $x$ that is above every element of $A$ and below every element of $B$. The first-born such number $x$ is denoted $$x=\{A\mid B\}.$$
In particular, when $B$ is empty, this means that $A$ is bounded above, and $\{A\mid\ \ \}$ is the first-born upper bound. Every set of surreal numbers admits an upper bound, but there is never a least upper bound, unless $A$ has a largest element.
This saturation fact implies that the surreal numbers are universal for every linear order. If you have a linear order $\langle L,\leq\rangle$, a hierarchy of your own devising, then there is an order preserving map from $L$ into the surreal numbers. One simply carries out a transfinite analogue of Cantor's back-and-forth construction (but one needs only forth for this universality). Namely, by the axiom of choice enumerate the elements of $L$ as $p_\alpha$ for some $\alpha<\kappa=|L|$, and then define $p_\alpha\mapsto x_\alpha$ in the surreals recursively. At stage $\alpha$, let $L_\alpha=\{x_\beta\mid \beta<\alpha\text{ and }p_\beta\leq p_\alpha\}$, and $R_\alpha=\{x_\xi\mid \xi<\alpha\text{ and }p_\alpha<p_\xi\}$, and then map
$$p_\alpha\mapsto x_\alpha=_{\text{def}}\{L_\alpha\mid R_\alpha\}.$$
This construction is order-preserving at every stage, and thus embeds $L$ into the surreals.

(The figure is from my essay on The Surreal numbers.)
A modification of the argument enables one to preserve also the field structure, if indeed $L$ is a field, since one can ensure that $x_\alpha$ realizes the same type as $p_\alpha$ over the prior elements. So the surreals are universal for all ordered fields, including the Hardy fields.
One can handle class-sized orders and class-sized fields similarly, achieving universality for proper class structures, provided that the global choice axiom holds.
Since there are only continuum many functions on the reals, it seems to me that there are only a set of Hardy fields up to isomorphism, and so there are surreal numbers such that one can find suitable copies of any Hardy field below them.
But meanwhile, it seems to me that a given Hardy field can often have multiple copies in the surreals, as high as desired in the surreals, and so there will be no bound in the surreals that is above all possible copies of a Hardy field. The previous paragraph only bounds them up to isomorphism and not absolutely.

I edited the question to clarify I meant the maximal Hardy field (that is the Hardy field without additional restrictions). If so, is the surreal number ${H|}$ well defined? I assume that the germ of the function $f(x)=x$ corresponds to surreal $\omega$. Is there a natural embeeding?

It seems to me that there is not just one copy of your field in the surreal numbers, but many, as I mention in the final paragraph of my answer, and so your question is not well posed. The notation ${H\mid\quad}$ is only defined when $H$ is already a set of surreal numbers, which amounts to fixing a particular copy embedding that field into the surreals. But there are many.

But perhaps an expert on Hardy fields can explain why there might be a canonical one to choose? I'm not sure...

Well, $H$ is already a set of surreal numbers because I identify the germ of the function $f(x)=x$ as $\omega$, so any other germs expressible via $x$ are expressible via $\omega$.

@Anixx you may want to look at this Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transseries#Using_surreal_numbers

Part of the issue is that evaluating $f(\omega)$ is not fixed until one fixes a meaning for $f$ in the surreals, which is not determined from the field structure alone. This is a highly saturated structure with many automorphisms that move things around.

This is indeed difficult for my understanding as the operations on Hardy field seemingly do not coincide with operations on surreal numbers. for instance, in surreal numbers $\ln \omega=\omega^{1/\omega}$, but in Hardy field $\ln x\ne x^{1/x}$.

@SamHopkins thanks. It seems that the link claims that the transseries with $x$ taken to represent $\omega$ are isomorphic to the surreals with their usual field operations. How then  in surreal numbers $\ln \omega=\omega^{1/\omega}$, but in Hardy field $\ln x\ne x^{1/x}$ (this comes from https://mathoverflow.net/a/414742/10059)?

If Hardy field is class-sized, then it is isomorphic to the whole surreal numbers, no? So, we cannot find a surreal number greater than all the germs or am I wrong?

I thought every Hardy field is determined from a collection of differentiable functions on the reals. If so, then it has size at most continuum and is not a proper class.

Meanwhile, I brought the question to the attention of Philip Ehrlich, who has informed me that he is preparing to post an answer soon, which I expect will be very helpful.

But also, not every class-sized ordered field is isomorphic to the surreals, since we can make such fields of cofinality $\omega$, which are therefore not Ord-saturated.
