In hyperreal field, can ln(ε) and ln(ω) be expressed as infinite sums?
In the hyperreal field, we can use Taylor series to express e^(ε) and e^(ω) as:
e^(ε) = 1 + ε + (ε^2)/2! + ...
e^(ω) = 1 + ω + (ω^2)/2! + ...
Is it similarly possible to express ln(ε) and ln(ω) as infinite sums in terms of ε and ω?
Since 0 = ln(1) = ln(ε*ω) = ln(ε) + ln(ω),
we know ln(ε) = -ln(ω), so once we find one expression we can find the other.
For instance:
e^(ω) = 1 + ω + (ω^2)/2! + ...
ln(e^(ω)) = ln(1 + ω + (ω^2)/2! + ...)
ω = ln(1 + ω + (ω^2)/2! + ...)
from which we can derive a cheap answer:
ln(ω) = ln(ln(1 + ω + (ω^2)/2! + ...))
But I'm curious if ln(ω) can be expressed in terms of ω without the logarithm?
We see ln(ω) < ln(1 + ω + (ω^2)/2! + ...) = ω
which implies ln(ω) is possibly an infinite sum of roots of ω, such as:
ln(ω) = ω^(1/2) + ω^(1/3) + ...
or some such series.

Noble, this relates back to your previous post about ln(ω) in 2022.
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414730/in-surreal-numbers-what-is-ln-omega/414742#414742

That post was about the surreals, not hte hyperreals.

@Mikhail, thank you for helping me clarify my question.  Yes, my question is about the hyperreals, and I was piggybacking off of a previous post about the surreals.  My understanding is that the field of hyperreals is a subfield of the field of surreals, so I was hoping my question was related.

$\ln (x+1)= x-x^2/2+x^3/3-x^4/4+x^5/5-...$

To help avoid any misunderstanding that may arise for readers of this question, let me say that when understood in the usual sense, there are no nontrivial convergent sequences or series at all in the hyperreal numbers (and neither in the surreal numbers).
The reason is that the hyperreal numbers are usually understood to be countably saturated. This has a model-theoretic definition, meaning that every finitely realized type with countably many parameters is realized. But in the case of ordered fields, it can be expressed as the following property: whenever
$$x_0\leq x_1\leq x_2\leq\cdots \leq y_2\leq y_1\leq y_0$$
with $x_n<y_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then there is a number $z$ in between
$$x_0\leq x_1\leq x_2\leq\cdots <z< \cdots \leq y_2\leq y_1\leq y_0.$$
This saturation property prevents any nontrivial convergent sequence $x_n\to x$, unless it is eventually constant, since there will be various numbers $z$ in between, on each side.
Indeed, every countable set of hyperreal numbers is discrete in the hyperreal order. For this reason, one cannot apply any of the usual treatment of sequences and series from the real numbers in the hyperreal field.
Meanwhile, there is nevertheless a robust theory of sequences and series in the hyperreals, but using sequences and series indexed instead by $\mathbb{N}^*$, the nonstandard natural numbers, instead of merely $\mathbb{N}$. With this change, one can form hyperreal analogues of all the familiar sequences and series in the reals. The reason is that by the transfer principle, every assertion made in the real numbers about any such sequence or series is also true exactly the same in the nonstandard realm.
Thus, the radius of convergent of the nonstandard analogue of a power series remains the same as what it was.
For example, the series $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac 1{2^n}=\frac12+\frac14+\cdots+\frac1{2^n}+\cdots$$
does not converge in the hyperreals, since one is using the natural numbers only. But the much longer (uncountably so) series
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}^*}\frac 1{2^n}=\frac12+\frac14+\cdots+\frac1{2^n}+\cdots+\cdots=1$$
does converge to $1$.
In my essay on the surreal numbers, an elementary introduction, I mentioned this situation as a possible red flag for surreal calculus. To do calculus with the surreal numbers (or the hyperreals), one simply cannot expect to use sequences and series and convergence ideas in the same manner that one does with the real numbers. Rather, one must in a sense remount calculus entirely bottom-up on the new setting, using infinitesimals, saturation, and transfer.
Some accounts of nonstandard analysis seem to provide a way to avoid the issue by simply treating $\mathbb{N}^*$ as the genuine natural numbers, and then talking some the standard numbers as a special kind of number. In this way of speaking, the subject of nonstandard analysis is concerned with sequences and series, even though the index set is uncountable by the usual way of talking. In my experience, however, this practice often leads to confusion when mathematicians from other areas join in. And so I find it best to be clear about what one means.
(Lastly, let me add that unless one adopts additional axioms, it is not usually correct to refer to "the" hyperreals, since we have no categorical such structure. But see my recent paper How CH could have been a fundamental axiom for more about how it could have been different.)

By "hardcore standard analysis people" do you mean perhaps nonstandard analysis people (like Nelson)?

Oops, yes, but also M Katz,who has also answered here. I have edited.

(Regarding your parenthetical comment about "the" hyperreals, couldn't the same be said of "the" class $V$ of all sets and "the" category of sets?  And could our history have been different regarding those?  Sorry if this is slightly off topic. I enjoyed reading your paper on CH.)

@JesseElliott No, this is a different kind of independence. In ZFC, we can prove that there is a unique class of all sets, just like we can prove there is a unique complete ordered field up to isomorphism and a unique model of Dedekind arithmetic up to isomorphism. But we have no such account in ZFC of "the" hyperreals. We are lacking a categorical theory. (But in ZFC+CH, there is such a categorical account--the hyperreals are the smallest countably saturated real-closed field.)

Is $\mathbb R$ of IST categorical?

@MikhailKatz That is indeed the question. If CH fails, then in ZFC there are many nonisomorphic countably saturated real-closed fields of size continuum. Presumably this would show up in IST as non-categoricity for $\mathbb{R}$ (that is, for what other people call the hyperreals $\mathbb{R}^$). I would want to hear from the IST experts. Same question for $\mathbb{N}$. I have pointed to the lack of a categoricity result for $\mathbb{R}^$ as an important part of the explanation for hesitancy toward nonstandard analysis in mathematics.

I think you may be changing the subject.  ZFC is a subtheory of IST, and ZFC proves that $\mathbb R$ is categorical.  Therefore this remains true in IST.

I see. I wonder what is the IST analogue of the noncategoricity of $\mathbb{R}^*$ in ZFC+$\neg$CH?

I think it has to do with the non-categoricity of the concept of "standard" and "nonstandard". A given IST set theoretic universe can admit diverse inequivalent standardness concepts in such a way so as still to realize IST, and they do not all have isomorphic $\mathbb{R}$s.

Please don't forget to ping me (I just noticed your last two comments by accident).  In response to your first comment: One can certainly construct $\mathbb R^\ast$ in IST but this would of course involve a different notion of standardness than the one built into IST.  And of course these hyperreals will not be categorical (for the $\mathbb R^\ast$ notion of standardness).

@MikhailKatz No, we are talking about different things, and this is now a side issue to the main question, so perhaps best to just drop it. (I was not referring to constructing $\mathbb{R}^*$ inside IST, but rather to the question of whether the concept of "standard" is categorical in a given model of IST, and I believe that it is not. Since "standard" is not definable in the internal language, it follows by the Beth definability theorem that there will be models with the same sets, but different notions of standardness.)

I believe that I can prove that it is consistent with IST that from the given notion of standardness we can define another alternative notion of standardness, which also fulfills IST in the same universe of sets.

Which logic are you applying the Beth definability theorem to?  How would the undefinability of st imply the existence of distinct notions of standardness?  Are you saying that it implies it, or merely that this would be consistent with IST?

@JoelDavidHamkins, thank you for these insights. I read your linked article. I think I understand the distinction you're making (I am new to this study). Please confirm I understand you:   The 'real' Taylor series for log(1+x) is x - (x^2)/2 + (x^3)/3 - ..., but this does not converge in the hyperreals unless it is written as log(1+x) = x - (x^2)/2 + (x^3)/3 - ..... + (x^N)/N + ....    Is this what you are saying about being more clear about saying "a power series converges in the hyperreals"?  In my answer (below), would you agree that: ln(ϵ) = -(1-ϵ) - ((1-ϵ)^2)/2 - ... - ((1-ϵ)^N)/N - ...

@euclidub IMO, it notationally makes the most sense to let the ellipsis … denote going to $\infty$ (not $\omega$), a "fictitious element" greater than all elements of the structure, which just happens to be "bigger" in the hyperreal numbers than the real numbers. This notational choice is alluded to in the second-last paragraph of this answer.

@JoelDavidHamkins, thank you for your continued guidance.  I hear you saying the ellipsis traditionally implies the regular infinity of the real natural numbers, unless you otherwise specify, n∈N∗.  If I understand you correctly, you would talk about a convergent sequence using your sigma notation above, using n∈N∗.  That said, how would you express the Taylor series for log(1+x) in a hyperreal number system? Would it look like this:  Sigma, n∈N∗, of ((-1)^(n+1))(x^n)/n ?  Or, written out like this:    Sigma, n∈N∗, of x - (x^2)/2 + (x^3)/3 - (x^4)/4 + .... + ((-1)^(n+1))(x^n)/n + ....

For positive $\epsilon$, the expression $\ln \epsilon$ will be equal to its power series at $x=1$ (in the $\delta, N$ sense).
To help avoid any misunderstanding that may arise for readers of this question, let me say that when understood in the usual $\delta, N$ sense, there are indeed nontrivial convergent sequences in the hyperreal numbers (though perhaps not in the surreal numbers).
Indeed, since $\epsilon>0$ is in the open disk of convergence at the point $1$, the usual condition will hold namely that for every $\delta>0$ there exists and $N>0$ such that partial sums of length at least $N$ will be within $\delta$ of the value $\ln \epsilon$.  Of course, for nonstandard points one may have to choose a nonstandard $N$, as in our case.
This follows by applying the transfer principle.  As far as $\ln \omega$ is concerned, it certainly cannot be given by a power series because $\omega$ falls outside the radius of convergence, seeing that $\omega>2$.

Thank you, @Mikhail.
I agree the value of ln(ε) can be found using the power series at x = 1:
ln(ε) = (ε-1) + (-1/2)(ε - 1)^2 + (1/3)(ε-1)^3 + (-1/4)(ε-1)^4 + ...
which simplifies to a sum of powers of ε, yielding the standard part:
St[ln(ε)] = -1 - 1/2 - 1/3 - ...
However, while ω falls outside of the radius of convergence, we still have the log identity
ln(ω) = ln(ε^(-1)) = -ln(ε)
which implies
ln(ω) = - ( ln(ε) )
giving
St[ln(ω)] = 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ....
I am wondering if the log identity gives a valid workaround to find ln(ω).

Since the standard part is only defined for limited numbers, it cannot be applied to $\ln \epsilon$ which is unlimited.

Thank you, @Mikhail.  Setting the standard part aside, does the log identity hold,   ln(ω) = -ln(ε), such that even though ω is outside the radius of convergence, we can nevertheless define a series that sums to ln(w), namely ln(w) = -ln(ε) ?

If $\epsilon>0$ is infinitesimal and $\omega=\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ then by the transfer principle $\ln \omega = -\ln \epsilon$.  This has nothing to do with power series expansions. Once we have this identity, we can bypass the radius of convergence issue, and express $\ln\omega$ as a power series in $\epsilon$ (just by chaning the sign).

Thank you, @Mikhail!  This answers my original question, which I admit I might not have asked well.  This is my first time posting on StackExchange.  So, the answer to my question is:  Yes, we can express ln(ω) as a power series because ln(ω) = -ln(ϵ).  And in general, for any number m > 1 that falls outside of the radius of convergence, we can express ln(m) as a power series in terms of 1/m because:   since m > 1, we have -1 < 1/m - 1 < 0, which means (1/m - 1) is inside the radius of conv., which means:  ln(m) = -ln(1/m) = -ln(1 + (-1 + 1/m)) can be expressed with a power series.  Yes?

I will propose an answer my question.  Please let me know if I have spoken accurately.
Within the hyperreal field (that is, the most traditional hyperreal field as described by some of the original texts on the subject by Robinson, Goldblatt, Keisler, and Henle), can we express ln(ϵ) and ln(ω) as a power series in terms of ϵ and/or ω?  (That is, where ϵ is infinitesimal, ω is infinite, and ϵ = 1/ω.)
Yes:
ln(ω) =  (1-ϵ) +  ((1-ϵ)^2)/2 +   ((1-ϵ)^3)/3 +   ((1-ϵ)^4)/4 + ....
ln(ϵ)   = -(1-ϵ) + -((1-ϵ)^2)/2 + -((1-ϵ)^3)/3 + -((1-ϵ)^4)/4 + ....
These results are indeed related by the log identity ln(ω) = -ln(ϵ), but can both be derived independently from the Taylor series for natural logarithm
ln(1 + x) = x - (x^2)/2 + (x^3)/4 - (x^4)/4 + ...
whose radius of convergence is |x| < 1 and x = 1.
PROOF:
First, find ln(ϵ).
Since the infinitesimal ϵ is in the radius of convergence, we can directly let x = -1 + ϵ:
ln(ϵ) = ln(1 + (-1+ϵ)) = (-1+ϵ) - ((-1+ϵ)^2)/2 + ((-1+ϵ)^3)/3 - ((-1+ϵ)^4)/4 + ...
We can rewrite this expression more neatly as:
ln(ϵ) = -(1-ϵ) - ((1-ϵ)^2)/2 - ((1-ϵ)^3)/3 - ((1-ϵ)^4)/4 - ...
After expanding the right side and gathering all the standard terms, we see an expression that clearly diverges to negative infinity as expected:
ln(ϵ) = -1 - 1/2 - 1/3 - 1/4 - .... + (all of the non-standard terms)
Second, find ln(ω).
To do this, I will derive a transformed Taylor series for ln(m) whose radius of convergence is any real number m > 1.
Assuming m > 1,
we have 1 > 1/m > 0,
which can be rewritten as 0 > -1 + 1/m > -1.
Therefore, (-1 + 1/m) is within the radius of convergence of the Taylor series used above.
Thus, we can rewrite ln(m) as:
ln(m) = ln((1/m)^-1) = -ln(1/m) = -ln(1 + (-1 + 1/m))
and can now use the given Taylor series using x = -1 + 1/m:
ln(m) = -ln( 1 + (-1 + 1/m)) = (1-1/m) + ((1-1/m)^2)/2 + ((1-1/m)^3)/3 + ((1-1/m)^4)/4 + ....
This is a convenient result in and of itself because radius of convergence of this Taylor series for ln(m) is any real m > 1.
By transfer principle, since ω > 1, we can use ln(m) to find:
ln(ω) = (1-1/ω) + ((1-1/ω)^2)/2 + ((1-1/ω)^3)/3 + ((1-1/ω)^4)/4 + ....
and since 1/ω = ϵ, we have:
ln(ω) = (1-ϵ) + ((1-ϵ)^2)/2 + ((1-ϵ)^3)/3 + ((1-ϵ)^4)/4 + ....
which is indeed the opposite sign of the result for ln(ϵ):
ln(ϵ) = -(1-ϵ) + -((1-ϵ)^2)/2 + -((1-ϵ)^3)/3 + -((1-ϵ)^4)/4 + ....
In both cases, after expanding the terms and gathering all the standard terms, we see expressions that clearly diverge to infinity as expected:
ln(ϵ)   = -1 - 1/2  - 1/3  - 1/4  - .... + (all of the non-standard terms in terms of ϵ)
ln(ω) =  1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + .... + (all of the non-standard terms in terms of ϵ)

I didn't downvote, but you can't "gather all the standard terms" because there are infinitely many terms in the sum.

@MikhailKatz, thank you; I really appreciate your continued feedback. I see how my use of "gathering terms" was not precise. I was trying to make clear that the value of ln(ω) diverges based solely on the sum of the harmonic series, without there being any 'ω' terms in the expansion. Other than that detail, was my analysis of ln(ω) and ln(ϵ) otherwise correct? Did I correctly transform the power series for log(1+x) (with radius |x|<1) into the power series for log(m) (with radius m>1)?  Ultimately, is it fair to say ln(ω) = (1-ϵ) + ((1-ϵ)^2)/2 + ... and
ln(ϵ) = -(1-ϵ) + -((1-ϵ)^2)/2 + ... ?

Yes, when $\epsilon$ is interpreted as a hyperreal infinitesimal and $\omega$ its hyperreal inverse (certainly not the countable ordinal/cardinal).

Thank you!!!  I appreciate your help, @MikhailKatz
